# On Click: Open a Pop-up Div on a Different Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, onclick

On page1.php I have a `click` event that causes the user to be redirected to page2.php. It goes something like this:

```
$("#someButton").click(function() {
    window.location = "page2.php";
});
```

And that works great. But what I really want is to open a hidden, UI-blocking `<div>` on page2. The user can already open this `<div>` manually by clicking another button on page2, that goes something like this:

```
$('#someOtherButton').click(function() {
   $("#pageContainer").block({message: $("#theDivIWant2See")});
});
```

Can I make a `click` event from the JavaScript on one page call the JavaScript on another? Or will I need to add in some HTML-parsing to pass information between pages? (I'm not looking for a JavaScript hand-out here, just a strategy to help me move forward.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you redirect from the first page, add a querystring value in your url. and in the second page, using your server side page language, set in in a hidden field and in the document ready event check the value of that hidden field. If the value is expected, call a javascript function to show the popup.

Some thing like this

```
$("#someButton").click(function() {
    window.location = "page2.php?showpopup=yes";
});
```

and in page2.php set it (forgive for errors, i am not a php guy)

```
<input type='<?php $_GET["showpopup"] ?>' id='hdnShow' />
```

and in the script

```
$(function(){
  if($("#hdnShow").val()=="yes")
  {
    //Call here the method to show pop up
  }
});
```

Comment: THAT is really interesting. It would mean having an extra hidden input lying around. But it I could pass other (page specific) parameters in place of that "yes" and get a lot more functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do your stuff when DOM for page2 is ready. You can use jQuery's ready function for that.

> $(document).ready(function() {
>     // put code for showing your div here
>   });

Hope that helps.

Comment: The code to display the `<div>` of interest is already called inside that document.ready (in page2).  My problem is, how do I know if I have just been forwarded from page1?

Answer (score 0):

Could you pass a query string argument or assign a cookie that the other page could then check when the document loads?  If the value exists then present a modal dialog (e.g. jQuery UI Modal Popup)

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/